# Extend a class from MapActivity or Activity depending on installed libraries

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Imagine that I have a camera app where I show a small MapView in one corner showing where is the device located. So I have to extend my activity from a MapActivity to do that.

Then imagine that I want to release my app in a device without Google Apis, like the Kindle, for instance. As the MapActivity does not exist anymore, I should extend from a regular Activity.

I know that I can set

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
```

To let the user install the app even if the library is missing. And then use

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.google.android.maps.MapView");
        googleMapsEnabled = true;
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        googleMapsEnabled = false;
    }
```

to check if the MapView class is present or not.

But the problem is the base class that I extend from, it should be Activity instead of MapActivity if Google Maps are not available.

My question is, how can I use the same code to support both options, without duplicating the whole code into different classes depending on the installed libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, my usual approach with things like this (ie: where I *have* to inherit from two different base classes in different scenarios, but ultimately want the same - or nearly the same - behavior) is to break out as much as I can of the common functionality into a static helper class that I call from both classes.

Comment: In my scenario, almost the whole app would be in this helper class, which is not an option as it is too complex

Comment: Hm. Not sure, then - and I'll admit, I'm not that familiar with your situation, but as a rule, if you're coding Java and you need to inherit from two different base classes, you have to create two classes. And if you don't want to duplicate things, you have to move them out into some reusable space.

If your whole app is in your class that inherits from Activity, would it make sense to break it down into smaller pieces that can be reused?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best option but sometimes you don't have the time to do the things the way they should be done.